# clr.Dll!MetaDataGetDispenser and higher than expected CPU usage

Tags: c#, wcf, diagnostics

I have a Windows Service written in C# which is running on a customer's server and seems to be working fine without any problems, but the CPU usage for this process is often much higher than I would expect. It is never over 50%, but is still a lot higher than the single figures I see when running in house.

This may simply be due to a higher workload, but I was attempting to determine what exactly the service was doing and process explorer is reporting a lot of threads with a start address of clr.Dll!MetaDataGetDispenser, each with small CPU Usage, but they all add up.

Does anyone know what this and what sort of code would be using it?

The service will be using WCF to connect to various clients (and presumably that will involve some sort of serialisation) and will also be accessing a Microsoft SQL Server, but no explicit reflection.

Comment: You can use JustTrace or DotTrace and attach one of them to your windows service.